# Dockerfile creation of Node.js application

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, dockerfile, aws-sdk

I have been trying to build a Docker image for a Node.js application. The node.js application tries to access a s3 bucket in aws and displays the information on a web-page.But when I'm trying to build the image it shows this error:

[image]

The Dockerfile that I've created looks like this :

```
FROM node:8
COPY package.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
EXPOSE 3000
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

The node.js file looks like :

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3000

//configuring the AWS environment
AWS.config.update({
    accessKeyId: '',
    secretAccessKey: ''
  });


var s3 = new AWS.S3();

var params = {
    Bucket: 'demo-azure',
    Key : 'test.txt'
  };

  var response = `<html><body><h1>`

  s3.getObject(params,function(err,data){
    if(err)console.log(err,err.stack);
    else{
        console.log(data.Body.toString());
        response += `Hello from ` + data.Body.toString() + `</h1>` 
    }
  });

  app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send(response));

  app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`))
```

What can I try next?

Comment: `node:8`. If thats pulling a version 8 of node, pretty old now.  Maybe try a newer version.

Comment: _Step 1/6 : FROM node:14.3.0
Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: dial tcp: lookup registry-1.docker.io on 10.0.2.3:53: read udp 10.0.2.15:39604->10.0.2.3:53: i/o timeout_ - got this error I changed the version to 14.3.0

Comment: You say "it shows this error", and then you have an image; does it print out a text error message that you can include in the question instead?  Instead of showing pictures of your code, can you include the actual code of your Dockerfile and Node application?

Comment: I have added the code as text.

Comment: There seems to be a problem with the networking of your Docker installation, not so much with the Dockerfile itself! I suggest reinstalling Docker.

Comment: this https://github.com/StefanScherer/dockerfiles-windows/issues/270 may help

Comment: Thank you everyone. Don't know what the problem was but I restarted everything again and it's working now.